# Java Byte Shift

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have a byte array that should be treated as 2 bytes of unsigned data.
So code below represents 257. I am trying to store it as short, but I am getting an error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable. Is there any clever way to do this? Please help.

```
    byte[] unsigned2ByteNum = new byte[2];
    unsigned2ByteNum[0] = 1;
    unsigned2ByteNum[1] = 1;

    short port = 0;
    (byte)(port >> 8) = portNum[0];
    (byte)(port) = portNum[1];
```

Comment: You'll have to shift the right hand side of the assignment, not the left hand side.

Answer (score 3):

You got this backwards. You can't assign a value to an expression, you can only assign a value to a variable.

```
short port = (short) ((portNum[0] << 8) | (0xff & portNum[1]));
```

This is assuming `portNum[0]` is the high byte.

EDIT : corrected the conversion to treat a negative low byte as unsigned (so that, for example, {1,-1} will be converted to 511 instead of -1).